# Looking for a java web framework that support django styled url handling

Tags: java, django, url, frameworks

I'm looking for a java web framework that will allow you to configure dynamic urls where information is being passed to the controller.

For example

/{clientName}/login

would call the same controller regardless of the clientName and pass that clientName as an accessible value or an object in it's own right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) @Controllers allows that kind of request mappings in a very simple way.  See "15.3.2 Mapping requests with @RequestMapping" for details.

```
@Controller
public class AppointmentsController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/appointments/{day}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Map<String, Appointment> getForDay(@PathVariable int day) {
        ...
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/appointments/new")
    public AppointmentForm getNewForm() {
        ...
    }
}
```

It is available since Spring 2.5.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`UrlRewriteFilter`](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) to rewrite the URLs (for the sake of them being "pretty") for any java web framework.

In addition, there is [PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/) for JSF.

Answer (score 1):

SpringMVC can be configured for this kind of URL routing since version 2.5. You have tu use annotations as described in http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django on Jython.

Comment: I think the OP meant in the Java language.